# "To be back to/at work", which preposition is the correct one?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I am studying with the book ["Grammar in Use" by Raymond Murphy (2019 ed.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Grammar_in_Use), going through phrasal verbs. I found this example at pag. 275.

> My holidays are nearly over. Next week I'll be back **at** work.

Is it a mistake?
I've only just heard "to be back **to** work". The COCA corpus agrees with me.
What do you think and why?

1. My holidays are nearly over. Next week I'll be back **at** work
2. My holidays are nearly over. Next week I'll be back **to** work

Comment: Can you please clarify in what way you think the sentence is mistaken? Perhaps a link to the search you did on the COCA?

Comment: Location uses at. We were at work when he called. We went back to work before noon. Both are fine. Just expressed two different ways.

Answer (score 2):

I believe, the issue is the verb:

Be ( static, location) - requires AT - be/stay at work

Go/return (movement) - requires TO - go/return to work

Answer (score 1):

These aren't really phrasal verbs. "at" refers to being in or near a location or state. "to" refers to a destination. If you are working, you are at work. If you are returning from a vacation with work as your destination, you are going back to work. Both are correct, and both are the standard, non-phrasal meaning of the prepositions, and they follow "back", not a verb.

As a side note, I'm not sure what punctuation mark you're using for contractions, but it's not the standard apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

Murphy is correct.

It *is* more common to hear someone say, "Get back to work."
Or "I'm going back to work."

However, in this construction, Murphy is correct, but I would use a comma after the clause: "Next week,"

You second sentence Would be correct like this:

Next week, I'll be going back to work.

Or you could say, "Next week, I'll be back on the job."